# Converting .asmx to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, .net-3.5, asmx

I'm developing a .NET 3.5 webservice using .asmx pages, but the fact that i cant use optional parameters in the GET and POST requests is making me think 
in switch my application to WCF. But I didnt understand clearly how it works.

Can you show me how the below code would be if converted to WCF?

```
[WebService]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class ws :WebService
{
    #region WebMethods

    //Parameters shoud be optional but it isnt possible in .asmx .NET 3.5
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlNode GetResult(string param1(=null), string param2(= null))
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        //Get a xml string
        string output = myClass.GetXmlString(param1, param2);

        //Load this xml
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(output);

        //Return this xml
        return xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSDL cannot describe optional parameters, so it wouldn't matter if you are using ASMX or WCF contracts, the actual semantics of using optional parameters is redundant (they are still classed as required parameters - i.e. like all parameters).

Comment: After read this http://goo.gl/YfBRs I assume that using WCF i could have optional parameters. Wrong?

Comment: So what's the solution when i need to have optional with the same message name? I think about using normal .aspx pages, and manually handle parameters, but it looks ugly to me

Comment: You will never have actual .NET "optional" parameters. You may be able to create a service where the WSDL permits a parameter to be missing, but I think you may need to process it as XML. I don't know whether a WCF data contract can handle missing parameters of an integer type. They will still not be "optional", but maybe would be `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't process requests as xml, only POST requests with named parameters are allowed. For now I switched to a normal aspx page so I can handle all parameters sent. Is there another solution?